# dealing with highcharts bar chart with really long category names

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a bar chart built with Highcharts that uses categories for its x-axis--really long wordy categories.  **I can't figure out a good way to make sure categories always stay on one line**. I cannot abbreviate them unless I can use a tooltip or something to show the long version upon mouse hover-over or some other intuitive user interaction.  When the categories line-wrap, it starts to look like a wall of text.

**Any ideas for displaying long categories and data in a clean way**?  I'm willing to consider a different type of chart as long as it displays the data in a clear and nice-looking way.  I'd like to stick with Highcharts but only if possible.

**EDIT**:
After much effort, I've given up on the idea of adding a tooltip to an x-axis category label in a cross-browser (IE6+) way.  Even with JQuery it doesn't seem possible or practical.  I'm still looking for any solution which allows me to display these long categories nicely (I'm not happy with the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/67) I created earlier because hovering over the data bar is not obvious enough to the user).

A picture of the problem graph, with **categories blacked out:**
[image: Labels too long, going to next line]

JSFiddle Code:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id='mytoolTip'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa blahblahblah blah blah blah ', 'America blahblahblah blah blah blah ', 'Asia blahblahblah blah blah blah', 'Europe blahblahblah blah blah blah ', 'Oceania blahblahblah blah blah blah '],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function() {
                            return(this.value.substring(0,10) + "...");
                        }
                    }                            
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Population (millions)',
                        align: 'high'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        overflow: 'justify'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() { 
                       $("#mytoolTip").html(this.x + 'and the value is ' + this.y) ; 
                       return false ; 
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -100,
                    y: 100,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    shadow: true
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Year 1800',
                    data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
                }, {
                    name: 'Year 1900',
                    data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
                }, {
                    name: 'Year 2008',
                    data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
                }]
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: if you move the tool -tip to external `div` to have a better format  is that's answering your question

Comment: Yes, although I've considered this option already.  Any idea how to get the coordinates of the category labels?

Comment: what do you have in your mind to do with the category ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Try this fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/70/

We had a similar issue which we eventually solved by allowing the labels to use HTML. While we didn't go with the exact solution posted below, this should work for you as it uses the jQueryUI tooltip widget to show the full text on hover.

Note how I'm defining the xAxis.labels object.

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar',
                events: {
                    load: function (event) {
                        $('.js-ellipse').tooltip();
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa is the best place to do safari.  Label is soooo big that it iss ugly now.  =(.  -38023-8412-4812-4812-403-8523-52309583409853409530495340985 ', 'America is the best place you can ever live in ', 'Asia is the best food ever ', 'Europe best chicks ever on earth ', 'Oceania i dont know any thing about this place '],
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var text = this.value,
                            formatted = text.length > 25 ? text.substring(0, 25) + '...' : text;

                        return '<div class="js-ellipse" style="width:150px; overflow:hidden" title="' + text + '">' + formatted + '</div>';
                    },
                    style: {
                        width: '150px'
                    },
                    useHTML: true
            }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                   $("#mytoolTip").html(this.x + 'and the value is ' + this.y) ; 
                    return false ;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -100,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 1900',
                data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 2008',
                data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Where could we find the definition of .js-ellipse style? Thanks for sharing this solution.

Comment: an efficient way would be to use:

    var labelTooltip = '<style type="text/css">.labelTooltip{cursor:pointer}
    </style>';
                            $("head").append(labelTooltip);
    return '<div class="labelTooltip" style="overflow:hidden" title="' + text + '">' + formatted + '</div>';

Comment: I figured out the same solution as this. But this is not appealing either. Wondering whether anyone or Highcharts has figured out a way where there is an option to wrap up long labels into numbers of lines that can be specified, and truncate the rest with ellipsis.

Answer (score 6):

*working* [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/)

moving the tool tip :

HTML

```
    <div id='mytoolTip'></div>​
```

JavaScript

```
    tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {

               $("#mytoolTip").html(this.x + 'and the value is ' + this.y) ; 
                return false ; 
            }
        },
```

this is how you can get the category name from the tool-tip hovering

```
      this.key
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/5/)

Comment: Good answer--this may help.  I will give you credit if a better answer doesn't come along.  The only problem with this answer is it doesn't resolve the problem of category labels along the x-axis line wrapping when the screen size is is small or the labels really big: see http://jsfiddle.net/a6zsn/1/

Comment: you haven't told me what exactly is your plan with the category string

Comment: I need to be able to see the full, long version somewhere, but it can't line-wrap when it's an x-axis label.  An abbreviation is okay as long as the full category label is view-able (somewhere).  I might create an array of short labels mapped to an array of long-labels then use your jquery tooltip technique to create a custom tooltip.  If there is an easier solution though I'd love to see it.

Comment: I think this is enough to get me going.  I will use the formatter to added some ellipses to the x-axis label after a certain number of characters then use your tooltip with the full text.

Comment: see my final jsfiddle all you need to add to it is looping through the category

Answer (score 4):

Trim the labels

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['Foo afkhbakfbakjfbakfbnbafnbaf', 'Bar', 'Foobar'],
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value.substring(0, 8);
                }
            }
        },
```